# how to have different columns as different bars on x axis on a barplot

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a barplot which has the column names along the x axis with one bar to one column and have the corrosponding values of that columns data to be on the y axis and dictating how big the column is. Ideally I will then be able to split each bar into 2 based on half the bars representing the data from rows where another column has a 3 and the other half of the bar representing the rest of the data (unsure if that makes sense, added pictures!) My issue is that I haven't found a way to be able to involve more than two columns from a dataframe on a barplot let alone how to have multiple columns worth of data on just the x axis. For reference I am trying to do this with a view to run a multiple regression on all the variables involved if that changes anything!

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible or if I need to completely restructure the original dataframe to make it happen.

I have recreated some of the relevant columns below to demonstrate what it is I want them to do. For some reference the UEB_score is what I want to be used for the columns to be split in half so a 3 in UEB_score is one half and any other value in that column is the other bar. For all the columns with TUT in the title, the following activity is the different categories I want to measure and have it split up so its activities on x axis and TUT score on y axis and a key showing the split of the bars based on UEB score.

```
df 
#   UEB_score TUT_eating TUT_homework TUT_talking 
P1     0           0          0.5         0
P2     3           0.25       0           0.5 
P3     2           0.5        0           0 
P4     0           0.2        1           0.6
P5     1           0.5        0           0.25 
P6     3           0          0.75        0
```

I want the bar chart to look like this, this is one a colleague of mine made with slightly different labels (no i cannot borrow her code or get help from her!) - sorry for using a picture I have searched but dont know how to attach or create a barplot in here let alone how to make a 'fake' one that doesn't exist yet code wise!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7R7Q.png]

Any help would be HUGELY appreciated!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to make this with `ggplot2`. First, we `pivot` the data frame to a long structure. Each activity name goes to the column I called "TUT", and the respective score goes to a "score" column.

We're plotting each activity as a category on the x-axis, and the scores on the y. The different groups/bars are made by mapping the UEB_score variable to the `fill` aesthetic. `UEB_score == 3` makes two groups: TRUE (UEB_score == 3) and FALSE (its some other value), and I relabel those with `scale_fill_discrete`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('TUT'),
               names_to = 'TUT',
               values_to = 'score') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = TUT,
             y = score,
             fill = UEB_score == 3)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(0.7),
           width = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c('Low ADHD',
                                 'High ADHD')) +
  labs(x = 'Activity',
       fill = '')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>